# Julia - Linear combination of row-wise outer products

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

I have a matrix `A` of dimension `(n, m)` and a matrix `B` of dimension `(n, p)`. For each of the `n` rows, I would like to compute the outer product between the row of `A` and the row of `B`, which are `(m, p)` matrices. I then have a vector `x` of size `n` and I would like to multiply each of these matrices by the corresponding entry of `x` and sum everything up. How can I do that?

```
# Parameters
n, m, p = 100, 10, 3
# Matrices & Vectors
A, B, x = randn(n, m), randn(n, p), randn(n)
# Slow method
result = zeros(m, p)
for i in 1:n
    result += x[i] * (A[i, :] * B[i, :]')
end
```

Comment: Perhaps one option is using `@tullio`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the math, could you clarify what your need is? Your code runs, and I'm not sure if speed is your issue because it runs pretty fast already (`@time` reports 0.33s first run, 149us second). When I put it in a function to keep out of global scope, it sped up to 55us.

Comment: @BatWannaBe yes my issue is speed. I realise my question so far doesn't make too much sense, so I will improve my minimal working example so you can understand better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General tips to save time and memory:

1. Put code in a method instead of the global scope, and make sure every variable in that function comes from the arguments, not global variables. That way, Julia's compiler can infer the types of variables and optimize.
2. Reduce allocations where possible, and you have many opportunities. The changes here distinguish the `old_way` and `new_way` methods, and it causes a 5-6x speedup and reduction to 1 allocation.

   - When slicing an array, use `@view` to avoid default behavior of allocating a copy.
   - You can change `result` in-place with `.+=`. `+=` allocates a new array and reassigns the variable `result` to it.
   - For elementwise operations like `x[i] * ...`, chaining dotted operators fuses the underlying elementwise loops and reduces allocations of intermediate arrays.
   - A matrix multiplication of a column (Mx1) vector and a row (1xN) vector can be simplified to elementwise multiplication.

```
n, m, p = 100, 10, 3
A, B, x = randn(n, m), randn(n, p), randn(n)

# Methods below do not use the above global variables

function old_way(A, B, x, n, m, p)
  result = zeros(m, p)
  for i in 1:n
    result += x[i] * (A[i, :] * B[i, :]')
  end
  result
end

function new_way(A, B, x, n, m, p)
  result = zeros(m, p)
  for i in 1:n
    result .+= x[i] .* ( @view(A[i, :]) .* @view(B[i, :])' )
  end
  result
end

using BenchmarkTools

@btime old_way(A, B, x, n, m, p);
# 36.753 μs (501 allocations: 125.33 KiB)

@btime new_way(A, B, x, n, m, p);
# 6.542 μs (1 allocation: 336 bytes)

old_way(A, B, x, n, m, p) == new_way(A, B, x, n, m, p)
# true
```

The example above avoided global variables so far, and the example below will show why. Even if you put your code in a method but still use global variables, not only is the performance just generally worse, trying to reduce allocations *backfires*:

```
# Methods below use n, m, p as global inputs

function old_oops(A, B, x)
  # same code as old_way(A, B, x, n, m, p)
end

function new_oops(A, B, x)
  # same code as new_way(A, B, x, n, m, p)
end

@btime old_oops(A, B, x);
# 95.317 μs (1802 allocations: 153.48 KiB)

@btime new_oops(A, B, x);
# 235.191 μs (1302 allocations: 81.61 KiB)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another verison

```
# Parameters
n, m, p = 100, 10, 3

# Matrices & Vectors
A, B, x = randn(n, m), randn(n, p), randn(n)

function old_way(A, B, x)
    # Slow method
    result = zeros(m, p)
    for i in 1:n
        result += x[i] * (A[i, :] * B[i, :]')
    end
end

function another_way(A, B, x)
    sum(xi * (Arow * Brow') for (xi, Arow, Brow) in zip(x, eachrow(A), eachrow(B)))
end
```

And benchmarking:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @benchmark old_way(A, B, x)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):   83.495 μs …   2.653 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 95.79%
 Time  (median):      87.500 μs               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   101.496 μs ± 115.196 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  6.46% ±  5.53%

  ▃█▇▆▂    ▁ ▁        ▁                                         ▁
  ███████████████▇█▇██████▆▇▇▇▆▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▆▇▆▆▇▆▇▅▆▆▆▄▅▅▅▅▆▅▆▅▅▅▄▅ █
  83.5 μs       Histogram: log(frequency) by time        200 μs <

 Memory estimate: 153.48 KiB, allocs estimate: 1802.


julia> @benchmark another_way(A, B, x)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  25.850 μs … 923.032 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 95.94%
 Time  (median):     27.477 μs               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   31.851 μs ±  35.440 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  5.03% ±  4.49%

  ▇█▇▅▃▁           ▁▁▁                                         ▁
  ███████▇▇▆▇████████████▇█▇▇▇▆▇▆▅▆▆▆▅▆▆▅▆▆▇▆▅▅▅▆▅▆▅▅▅▄▃▅▅▅▄▄▄ █
  25.8 μs       Histogram: log(frequency) by time      77.4 μs <

 Memory estimate: 98.31 KiB, allocs estimate: 304.
```

So it's a little faster, and uses a little less memory.

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

If your setup has the same structure as your MWE, using LinearAlgebra:

```
faster(A,B,x) = (diagm(x)*A)'*B
```

runs 4x faster:

```
using LinearAlgebra, BenchmarkTools

# Parameters
n, m, p = 100, 10, 3
# Matrices & Vectors
A, B, x = randn(n, m), randn(n, p), randn(n)
# Slow method

function slow(A,B,x)
    result = zeros(m, p)
    for i in 1:n
        result += x[i] * (A[i, :] * B[i, :]')
    end
    result
end

faster(A,B,x) = (diagm(x)*A)'*B

@assert(slow(A,B,x) ≈ faster(A,B,x))
@btime slow($A,$B,$x)     # 113.400 μs (1802 allocations: 139.39 KiB)
@btime faster($A,$B,$x)   # 28.100 μs (4 allocations: 86.41 KiB)
```